# Docker, Why Sudo Doesn't Work as Expected?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sudo

**Note: Everyone is pointing to other problems and yet ignoring my main problem...**

My docker file looks like this:

```
# BUILD: docker build -t default_credentials ./
# RUN: docker run -u root -t -i default_credentials

FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM python:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

ADD default_credentials ./default_credentials

RUN pip3 install -r ./default_credentials/requirements.txt

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \ 
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nmap

RUN apt-get -y install sudo

CMD /bin/bash
```

When it starts running I type:

```
 sudo nmap -PE -sn 10.0.0.2
```

But the output doesn't contain the device mac address which means nmap didn't run with high privileges, how can I fix this?

Please Note: Only if I run nmap on my PC as sudo it shows the mac address, else it won't report the mac address.

Comment: You're already `root` within that container, so there is no point using `sudo`.

Comment: Your container is running on a bridge network that Docker creates to isolate it. If you want it to have direct access to the host network, you should add `--network=host` to the options on your `docker run` command.

Comment: @Mushroomator not using root gives same output, ie no mac address

Comment: @HansKilian tried that as well, output didn't change. `docker run -u root -t -i --network=host default_credentials`

Comment: A Docker container runs in an isolated environment.  If you need access to things like the host network interface, it's often better and easier to run these processes directly on the host than to put them into Docker and then disable its isolation features.

Comment: @DavidMaze yet that doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: How is "There is no point to using sudo" not an answer to your question? You don't _need_ sudo here. It will not give you any privileges you don't already have. If you're having an nmap problem, **`sudo` will not fix it.**

Comment: If the problem is that nmap needs _real_ root, not unprivileged-container root, `sudo` won't fix that. Instead, you need to configure your container to run privileged.

Comment: That said, it's also possible that it's not a privilege issue but instead a network-stack issue. Remember, Docker containers don't get access to your physical Ethernet adapter; there's a NAT layer between them and the actual network. So it may even be that _both_ `sudo` _and_ running in a privileged container wouldn't fix the problem, depending on that problem's details. (It's possible to set up bridged networking in Docker, which would give you ARP data so nmap could show Ethernet addresses, but it's a fair bit of extra work).

Comment: What you're calling your "main" problem, then, is really your _immediate_ problem. The _main_ problem -- the thing you actually care about solving -- is getting a MAC address from nmap; the fact that you asked about something else -- about sudo -- makes this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/144918).

Answer (score 1):

> **But the output doesn't contain the device mac address which means nmap didn't run with high privileges**, how can I fix this?

This assumption is not well-founded. There are multiple reasons nmap can not have access to ethernet addresses; not being run with root privileges is only one of them, and fixing the other problems is not `sudo`'s job.

- By default, Docker containers do not have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, and their root users may be mapped to a non-root user on the kernel. This makes root inside a container less privileged than root outside a container -- no matter whether or not you're using `sudo` -- unless you run the container in privileged mode.
- Having access to MAC addresses requires bridged rather than routed networking (as when going through a router, all ethernet frames have the address of the router). Docker networking is routed through an internal NAT layer by default. https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ describes how to set up bridged networking in Docker; for what you're doing to work, you need to have a physical ethernet device attached to the same bridge as your Docker container.

So `sudo` doesn't work as you expect because it's not *supposed* to fix every possible problem that could stop nmap from being able to see MAC addresses; it only fixes the problem of not running as root.